# Modifying a Method to Use Wildcard Characters to Print Data From a Generic Linked List With Two Type Parameters?

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters

I'm actually just very confused about the wording of this question, here is the method in question:

```
void print(LinkedList lt) {
    if (lt.size() == 0)
        System.out.println("  list is EMPTY.\n");
    for (lt.go_to_first(); lt.cursor_ok(); lt.step_fwd()) {
        System.out.println(lt);
    }
}
```

Basically just traversing a LinkedList, printing the data in each node as it goes along. This question asks me to modify this method, to print data from a generic linked list with two type parameters. Does this mean I have to modify the LinkedList class into a generic class with two type parameters? Or am I understanding it wrong?

The biggest problem I'm having with this is that everything is just so vague. I was provided with a LinkedList class that I was told to make into a generic class, which I did. However, modifying it to have two type parameters would mess up the rest of the code provided to me, which made me think I was going down the wrong path.

Original Question edit: Modify the method print to use Wild Card characters to print the data in a generic linked list with two
type parameters. Note: don’t make this method a generic-method.

Comment: could you actually include the original task description

Comment: I don't know how list could have two types parameters as it should be parametrized by only type of the values. I believe You were simply asked to use <?> in your method declaration

Comment: Ah, Yes, that was my first thought as well but upon reading the question again I was confused by the wording. So just checking, in my original solution I intended to just change the declaration to:

void print (LinkedList<?> lt)

Comment: I am as confused as you, but this what I would do. Unless the LinkedList implementation you were given (it is not a standard java one) can have 2 type parameters

Comment: Hmm, I see, it seems that the LinkedList class provided shouldn't be able to support two type parameters because it is declared like :

LinkedList<Integer> intlist = new LinkedList<Integer>();

I modified it so that it could support one type parameter because I'm creating linked lists of different types.